# Showing data from database with AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, database, angularjs

I want to diplay data from db in my page  .

This is my code in
**JS** :

```
 $scope.save = function() {
   var data = {
     subject: $scope.composeStory.subject,
     body: $scope.composeStory.body
   }


   $http.post(
       "insert.php", {
         'subject': $scope.composeStory.subject,
         'body': $scope.composeStory.body
       }
     )
     .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       console.log("inserted Successfully");
     });
 };
```

and **Php**

```
include('config.php');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($data->subject);
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($data->body);
mysql_select_db("angular") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO story (subject,body) VALUES ('$subject', '$body')");
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";

$query = "SELECT * FROM story";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $subject = $row['name'];
    $body = $row['description'];
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Json**

```
[{"0":"","subject":"","1":"","body":""},
 {"0":"","subject":"","1":"","body":""},
 {"0":"Soheil","subject":"Soheil","1":"Sadeghbayan","body":"Sadeghbayan"},
 {"0":"adsas","subject":"adsas","1":"asdasdasda","body":"asdasdasda"},
 {"0":"Say","subject":"Say","1":"Something","body":"Something"}]
```

it saved to db perfectly , but i dont know how to display data from database to my page ?

Comment: don't use mysql_* functions.

Comment: It should be in the data parameter in your success function.

Comment: thx for answering , would you please help me with details ?
thx again

Comment: Could you post your json you are getting? just log the data object.

Comment: i dont know how to do it !! but i can see my data in database

Comment: Change console.log("inserted Successfully"); to console.log(data); and give me the results in an edit above saying Json: and create a code block.

Comment: updated it @Blackunknown

Comment: You need to fix your php errors first, obviously there is no name or description columns in that table

Comment: oh - yes i fixed that , sry for that

Answer (score 0):

For retrieval of data create a factory-service which would use `$http` GET method, with the `url` pointing to your php file which returns the `$data` array in the format: `echo json_encode($data);`

This is a recent example I posted on another question:

```
demoApp.factory('simpleFactory', ['$http', function($http){

    return {

        getCustomer: function(){

            return $http.get("json/customers.php").then(
                function(response){
                    var customers = [];
                    customers = response.data;
                },
                function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: so you mean , the right way is to use factory-service?

Comment: I believe that is the right way as, in essence, a factory/service is a provider - it's providing your data to the app. This way you're abstracting this database related code away from the controller, which should be as "thin" as possible

Comment: @user3642164 See my edit within my answer - there's an example of such a factory that should help you.

Comment: Np, good luck. Note: Make sure you don't forget to include the dependency on this factory/service in your controller!